# D3 remove parents of elements returned by exit

Tags: d3.js

The following code will remove old paths:

```
var join = svg.selectAll('path').data(data, function (d) {
  return d.label;
});
join.exit().remove();
```

Each `path` element that I am removing is contained within a `g` element containing everything I want to remove.

```
<g class="item">
  <text class="line-text">Label</text>
  <path class="line" d="..." style="stroke: #2ca02c;"></path>
</g>
```

So what I really want to do here is remove the `g` element, but calling `.remove()` only removes the `path` element. How can I remove the entire `g` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to bind the data to the `g` elements so that you operate on them. The quick and dirty way to do what you're asking for would be the following.

```
join.exit().each(function() { d3.select(this.parentNode).remove(); });
```

Comment: Hmm... turns out I was binding to the `g` so I just had to change `selectAll('path')` to `selectAll('g')`. Must have gotten mixed up somewhere. Thanks for the answer! I'll accept as soon as Stack Overflow allows me to.

Comment: Great! Good to know that you've been doing the proper thing all along :)

Comment: First day with D3. Just working through examples. :P